# Change vertical bias when there's not enough space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

## Problem

I have a TextView inside a ConstraintLayout. Consider the TextView is 20dp high, and I want it to be at the top of the ConstraintLayout with a margin of 50dp. However, the ConstraintLayout's height is not fixed, and it is possible to be less than 70dp, meaning the TextView may not fit in there. In that case, I'd like to centralize the TextView vertically within the ConstraintLayout.

## My approach

I tried the following layout:

```
<ConstraintLayout android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout works well when there's enough space in the ConstraintLayout to fit the TextView and the top margin. But when there's not, I'd need to change the vertical bias to 0.5 in order to centralize the TextView within the ConstraintLayout.

So is it possible to assign different biases (either in the XML or programatically) depending on whether there is or there isn't enough space to meet all the constraints? Otherwise, what other approach could be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to change the bias programmatically:

```
 ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
    set.clone(constraintLayout);
    set.setVerticalBias(R.id.your_textview_id, 0.5f);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

and here's a way to detect your screen resolution and check for height restrictions:

```
private static String getScreenResolution(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    return "{" + width + "," + height + "}";
}
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Your answer helped a lot, but I solved the problem slightly differently. I added an OnGlobalLayoutListener to the view tree observer that checks the actual height of the ConstraintLayout and compares it to the height of the TextView and its margins. After checking that there's not enough space, I change the vertical bias according to your first snippet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Milack27 That's alright, I'm glad you managed to have the effect you wanted, and thank you for accepting my suggestion as well!

Comment: @NikosHidalgo your answer is not working in case of AndroidX.

Comment: @jakirhussain ConstrainSet is a class in AndroidX. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I am not getting any error code running well but bias not set.

Answer (score 1):

In case of AndroidX you can use this code.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams setParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.mTextView.getLayoutParams();
setParams.horizontalBias = 0;//0.3f in case of other then zero.
setParams.verticalBias = 0;
holder.mTextView.setLayoutParams(setParams);
```